# Crawl a website, then download all files of a specific type based on the occurrence of a text string on a page

Tags: string, download, web-crawler

I believe I have a rather unique question. Or at least I was unable to find a solution to a similar problem.

I want to crawl a website and then on each page I want to search for a particular text string. If the text string is found I want to download all files of a specific type (PDF) that are linked to that page.

I would appreciate a complete answer but if anybody could just point me in the direction of the necessary software or framework that could to accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you going to use?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use wget command

```
wget -r --accept=mkv,mp3 --tries=10 http://www.rootofwebsite.test/base_url -o log
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Python with urllib and [pyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) (similar to jQuery) but there are also special frameworks for crawling and scraping like [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) in Python.

Search web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct software for doing this at one go, unless you are the owner of Google or Yahoo who can and do crawl websites on a regular basis.

Anyways jokes apart, with a little bit of programming you can easily do that. There is no need for any frameworks or any such thing.

You will need:

1. Any LAMPP package XAMP, WAMP.
2. CURL to get the pages
3. Regex to Parse the pages.([Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/))
4. wget to download the files or whatever you want to download.

You can easily check up on each of these by a simple search on Google. Curl will help you get the html files and store them as a string in a variable. Next you can use the preg_match or ereg_match functions in PHP to find the exact string and if present send a system call to wget to download the file. The linked website has a software which will help you gain a lot of info on the Regular Expressions (regex),